Rate of Small Alphabet Reed-Muller Codes
I am going over the Essential Coding Theory book and I am confused with a claim made about the rate of Reed-Muller codes on pg. 169:

Thus Reed-Muller codes generalize some previously known codes - some with large alphabets and some with small alphabets. Indeed if we wish the alphabet to be small compared to the block length, then we can pick $m$ to be a constant. For instance if we choose $m = 2$, we get codes of length $n$ over an alphabets of size $\sqrt{n}$, while for a given choice of relative distance $\delta$, the code has rate at least $\frac{(1-\delta)^2}{2}$. In general for larger values of $m$, the code has alphabet size $n^{1/m}$ and rate at least $\frac{(1-\delta)^m}{m!}$. (See Exercise $\color{red}{9.5}$.) Thus for small values of $m$ and fixed positive distance $\delta < 1$ there is a rate $R > 0$ such that, by choosing $q$ appropriately large, one get codes on infinitely long block length $n$ and alphabet $n^{1/m}$ with rate $R$ and distance $\delta$, which answers Question $\color{red}{9.0.1}$ in the affirmative.

I understand the derivation of the size of the alphabet. Could I get the reason or starting intuition on why the rate is at least $\frac {(1 - \delta)^2}{2}$ for bivariate RM codes? Thanks!

I was able to solve my own problem :).
Consider RM codes with $m = 2$ and arbitrary $r$. That is, we consider the space of bivariate polynomials over $\mathbb {F_q}$ with degree at most $r$, where $q = \sqrt n$ (to see this, the size of this space is $n = q^m$). Then, this code has dimension $k = \binom{r + 2}{2}$ and $1-\delta = r / q$.
Then the rate $R$ is calculated as
$$\begin{align*}R &= k/n \\ &= \frac {\binom{r + 2}{2}}{n} = \frac{(r + 1)(r + 2)}{2n} \\ &= \frac{(r + 1)(r + 2)}{2q^2} \\&\geq \frac{(r/q)^2}{2} = \frac{(1 - \delta)^2}{2}.\end{align*}$$
This is generalizable for all $m$. The piece I was missing was the calculation of $\delta$ in relation to $r,q$. Hope this helps someone else in the future!
